# how to change MaterialUI form dialog-box background color keeping text field color white

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, dialog

I want to change the Material-UI form dialog box background color but in doing so the text-field color is also changing...what should I do?

[image]

Comment: please avoid using screenshots and add the code directly to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the style of the component, here are a few links to the MUI docs for reference.
Here's the link to [React Dialogue's](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/) override CSS documentation. Here is a [second link](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog-title/#css) to overriding/ styling the component, and a [third](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog/).

Comment: Or perhaps try to include targeting the focus on the text-field text color too..

Comment: sx is not working on this for some reason